# Multitouch over multiple views

Tags: android, multi-touch

For **(single)touch** gestures, there is a *GestureOverlayView* view which can be placed over other views (Gridviews, Listviews ... ) and empty space and still detect touch correctly.

- How to make such thing for **multitouch** (pinch/zoomout) gestures? Over
  empty activity space it can be done with
  *ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener*, but what if i want
  to use such gesture over list for example?
- Do i have to implement ScaleGesture detector for every view inside
  activity explicitly or is there any **smarter way** of doing this?

/Edit: A little bit of more specification

Right now im doing this:

```
 //setup listener
overlay = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.CgestureOverlayView);
overlay.setGestureVisible(false);
overlay.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
```

But then when im using GestureOverlayView i have to implement this

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture)
```

problem is i don't have Raw gesture file because Gestures Builder does not allow me to build multitouch gestures. Where to implement mentioned MotionEvent handling?

Should i do something like this and then override GestureOverlayView.onTouchEvent() ? (Or i dont see your point because you can use OnTouchEvent even without GestureOverlayView)

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    overlay.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}
```

//Edit#2 Well in the end, i didn't had to use GestureOverlay, i caught those MouseEvents from ListView which fills the whole activity. Anyway when you have MotionEvents you dont have to define your own multitouch gestures, instead you can use *ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener* for processing such events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*GestureOverlayView* lets you set a listener of type *GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener*. The methods in this interface are passed the raw *MotionEvent*s that the *GestureOverlayView* is receiving.

From these events it should be possible to detect any gesture required, even multitouch ones.

Edit: Instead of using

```
overlay.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
```

you would use

```
overlay.addOnGestureListener(this);
```

This would give you the *raw MotionEvent*s that can be used to determine any multitouch gestures. From there you will need to do your own tracking of the touches and figure out when a multitouch gesture is happening and how much movement has taken place (I'm sure there are lots of sample code snippets for pinch to zoom)

Of course there is no reason you couldn't just write your own View class that did the same thing as *GestureOverlayView* except only with multitouch gestures, but if you still want the single touch gesture behaviour provided by *GestureOverlayView* then it this method would allow you to just add the multitouch support you need.

Comment: Hey, can you be a little bit more specific? I have edited my answer

Comment: I think that should explain it a bit better